# R programming xmlTreeParse XML content does not seem to be XML

Tags: r, xml-parsing

I use R to parse the xml https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/getdata%2Fdata%2Frestaurants.xml. This xml exists, but R remind me that it does not seem to be XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using http instead of https :

```
library(XML)
u <- "http://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/getdata%2Fdata%2Frestaurants.xml"
doc <- xmlTreeParse(u, useInternalNodes = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I learnt that xmlTreeParse does not work with https. While the solution recommended by Grothendieck would work, sometimes you have to use https for added security, so if that is your situation then it is better to load the library RCurl and get the document using getURL. You can then parse it in XML. It worked for me as follows:

```
library(RCurl)
library(XML)
temp <- getURL("https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/getdata%2Fdata%2Frestaurants.xml")
doc <- xmlTreeParse(temp, useInternalNodes = TRUE)
```